# OneDrive for Business - Way to see which files are being shared by every user

Tags: office365, onedrive

I'm fairly new the OneDrive and was wondering if there was a way to see who has access to what file? Specifically, is this file being shared internally? externally? If so, by whom?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Really Appreciate this!  Thanks Ken!